# Randomly select number and its index from an array in matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I have one array c=[1 2 3 4 5]; with possibly number of  duplicate numbers.
I want to randomly choose an element from a array as well as its index.
Can anybody help me..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour. Usually when you ask a question you show what you have already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I tried C(randi(numel(C)) gives me random number but how can i find index of that number as that number comes so many times in an array.

Comment: Try C(randi(numel(C),1)) where randi(numel(C),1) will be your index if you need it later on. Consider adding that to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [**`find`**](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html?refresh=true)

**Code:**

```
C = [1,2,3,4,5,4,4,5];  %// Example input. Change with your original array

no = C(randi(numel(C))) %// Your code to find a random number.
idx = find(C == no)    %// find all the indices matching the value of the number.
```

**Output:**

```
no =

 5


idx =

 5     8
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the index:

```
idx = randi(numel(c));
```

Then get the element from the array

```
val = c(idx);
```